# Using a VPS and VPN to route via a static IP

Tags: routes, ip, vpn, vps

I have a VPS with a couple of static IP addresses. My home connection is on a dynamic IP address and provider does not issue static IPs. I have a client I'm doing some work for that needs a static IP to allow remote access to connect to their VPN.

Is there any way I can give them my static VPS IP address and then set up some kind of VPN/routing so I can route traffic from my home PC via my VPS to the client? If so, is it likely to be laggy...

TIA, M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order: yes, yes.

If you have root access to a VPS you can set up something like [OpenVPN](https://openvpn.net/) quite easily and then have access to the VPN. The downside is that you may run in to latency issues especially due to encryption and the packet protocol you're using for it. You'll be able to limit any lag by using less encryption (which it sounds like you don't need anyway), enabling compression in your OpenVPN configurations & also using UDP instead of TCP (although you may drop a few packets here and there)

After you have OpenVPN set up on your server you can connect to it via something like [Tunnelblick](https://tunnelblick.net/) for macs, [OpenVPN GUI](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/downloads.html) for Windows or [OpenVPN Connect](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.openvpn.openvpn&hl=en_GB) for Android/iOS